# In C programming, what is the difference between for(int i=0; st[i]; i++) and for(int i=0; i<st[length of the array];i++)

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, conditional-statements, garbage

In the below program, while using st[i] on the for loop condition :

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
     int st[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; 
     int i; 
     for(i=0; st[i]; i++) 
         printf("\n%d %d %d %d", str[i], *(str+i), *(i+str), i[str]); 
     return 0;
}
```

Output:

1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8
-874149648 -874149648 -874149648 -874149648
32764 32764 32764 32764

In the below program, while using i<8 on the for loop condition:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
     int str[8] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; 
     int i; 
     for(i=0; i<8; i++) 
         printf("\n%d %d %d %d", str[i], *(str+i), *(i+str), i[str]); 
     return 0;
}
```

Output: 
input

1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8

Can anyone please explain what is happening over there in st[i]. If it is garbage value means why it stops after printing that two extra iteration.

Compiler: onlinegdb.com -c compiler

Comment: `st[i]` is a condition. And `i<8` is a condition. Former is true when`s[i]` is non zero. Latter - when `i` is less than `8`. Quite a difference.

Comment: Try `int st[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 0};` on the first one and see what you get.

Comment: Your first program runs past the end of `st[]` giving undefined behavior.  Change the definition of `st[]` to `int st[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0};` and see what happens.  The zero will stop it, buut I'm not sure why you want to do it that way.

Comment: If you've seen the first loop somewhere, you can be almost certain that the code was processing a C string. That's because C strings always end with a NUL character, which has the value 0. This technique does ***not*** work for any array, only for arrays which have a zero at the end, and no zeros anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A for loop will continue as long as the middle expression evaluates to true, i.e. a non-zero value.  So in this case:

```
for(i=0; st[i]; i++)
```

The loop continues as long as `st[i]` is not 0.  Since there are no elements of the array that contain 0, this ends up reading past the end of the array.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as an indeterminate number of seemingly random values being printed.

Answer (score 2):

In C, a condition is true if it evaluates to non-zero, and false if it evaluates to zero.

In the case where the condition is simply `st[i]`, it is implicitly comparing the value of `st[i]` with zero to determine whether the condition is true or false.  This is a pretty common thing when dealing with strings where the length is not already known (i.e. if it was passed as a pointer), since the null-terminator has a numeric value of zero.

In your case, the comparison makes no sense, since your array of `int` doesn't end with a value of zero, and you already know the length of it. Why not just pass 8? The condition of `st[i]` will invoke undefined behavior since you are guaranteed to go out of bounds with that array, since there is no element with the value of zero in it.

Answer (score 2):

`st[i]` may becomes zero (which means false in C)  on some unpredictable iteration as you read the elements past the array end. It is an UB and anything may happen.

modify

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
     int st[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0}; 
     int i; 
     for(i=0; st[i]; i++) 
         printf("\n%d %d %d %d", str[i], *(str+i), *(i+str), i[str]); 
     return 0;
}
```

and it will work as expected